# Trying to Scrape Table From a Vendor Portal But The Loop Isn't Appending The List. Using Python & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Language: Python
Tool : Selenium
Browser : Chrome

Hi, this is my first attempt at coding to make my life easier. I'm currently trying to scrape a table off from my customer's vendor portal. This is to automate a very manual and time-intensive process.

I've identified the XPATH of the table I'm trying to get. Below is a snippet of my code and how I'm trying to scrape it.

When I first did the loop, the list only had information from the last row. So I added the `print(len(rows))` to find out if anything was actually appended. To my dismay, it only printed 1,1,1,1,1,1 until the end of the loop. I believe the content in the list was being replaced, rather than being appended.

I'm not sure where I did wrong and would like your advice on it.

Additionally, I would also like to ask for some pointers if you have the time for it.

Since I'm going to do some cleaning after scraping the table, should I scrape every column and assign each column to a variable, or should I just scrape every row like how I'm doing now.

```
#Identify number of rows
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='docflow.list_DocFlowList']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr")
row_nos = len(rows)

#Get text from rows variable
#Range starts from 2 to exclude header
for i in range(2, row_nos):
    row = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='docflow.list_DocFlowList']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]")
    row_text = []
    for content in row:
        row_text.append(content.text)
    print(len(row_text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_text = []` should be declared outside of `for` loop. However, your code structure is over complicated

It can be fixed and simplified as below:

```
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='docflow.list_DocFlowList']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr")[1:]
row_text = [row.text for row in rows]
```